# Can't remove child from node after animation

Tags: javafx

I just worked with animations and I realized a problem. When I tried to remove child from parent after animation it does not worked.

```
FadeTransition needRestartBoxFadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200));
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setFromValue(1);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setToValue(0);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setNode(needRestartBox);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setAutoReverse(true);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setCycleCount(1);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setOnFinished(e -> removeNeedRestartBox());
```

(removeNeedRestartBox() is just removes needRestartBox from the parent)

How can I remove the child from the parent after animation?

Thanks for help and sorry for my bad english!



**EDIT:**
I have a StackPane extended class, what is the parent in this case.

```
//in constructor
Timeline needRestartBoxAnimation = new Timeline();
needRestartBoxAnimation.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(200), new KeyValue(needRestartBoxHeight, 100.0)));

FadeTransition needRestartBoxFadeOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200));
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setFromValue(1);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setToValue(0);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setNode(needRestartBox);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setAutoReverse(true);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setCycleCount(1);
needRestartBoxFadeOut.setOnFinished(e -> removeNeedRestartBox());

//show method
private void showNeedRestart(){
   needRestartBox.setMaxHeight(0);
   getChildren().add(needRestartBox);
   needRestartBoxAnimation.play();
}

//dispose method
private void disposeNeedRestart(){
   needRestartBoxFadeOut.play();
}

//remove child method
public void removeNeedRestartBox() {
   getChildren().remove(needRestartBox);
}
```

The timeline animation does not start while the parent is contains the needRestartBox. So the main problem is that the FadeTransition does not remove the needRestartBox.

I can send you the whole class if you want.

**EDIT 2:**

Now the child is removing properly, but the something is not working. If I don't use the fade transition, that is working well.

```
//working dispose method:
private void disposeNeedRestart(){
   removeNeedRestartBox();
}

//not working dispose method:
private void disposeNeedRestart(){
   needRestartBoxFadeOut.play();
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly isn't working? Do you get any errors? Is the child still present in the `children` list? Is there something wrong with the display?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue with the code provided. The animation properly runs, if `needRestartBoxFadeOut.play()` is called and if I print the size of the child list after removing the node, it's as expected. Add the `removeNeedRestartBox` method and show us where in the scene the node you want to remove recides (as question [edit]).

Comment: @Slaw, no i don't. The method is like not running. But if I put another function like System.out.println("Something"); for example I get the message.

Comment: Again I cannot reproduce the issue. The only issue I could reproduce was that the `needRestartBox` still had an opacity of 0 after calling `showNeedRestart` and `disposeNeedRestart`. A subsequent call of `showNeedRestart` adds the node to the `StackPane`, but it's still fully transparent.

Comment: @fabian thank you! The opacity was the problem. Then what about setAutoReverse(true)? I thought that reverses the opacity value to from value.

Comment: It would, but you have `cycleCount` set to `1`.